# suppress omniture s.t() call from generating a "second" pageview in a site with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, adobe-analytics

I've already searched the answer for these, but my problem is with a site that has an iframe.
The situation is: I've implemented de omniture tracking on a partner site (that a i don´t have control to modify) but the site has a iframe within and it makes the tracking script generate a second page view.
is there a way to supress the omniture s.t() call from generating a "second" pageview in a site with iframe

best regards my friends and thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
s.abort = self != top
```

If self == top, you're not in an iframe and want the the pixel to fire s.abort = false

If self != top you're in an iframe and want to stop the pixel s.abort = true

Another way to accomplish this is:

```
if(self != top)s.abort = true;
```

Comment: I don't have any live examples to point you towards but you can drop that in your s_code plugin section to see it in action.